# Cannot find php module of apache

Tags: php, apache-2.4, centos7

I am running Apache 2.4.52 on Linux CentOS 7 server. I have installed PHP 8.

Followed many blogs to configure Apache to run PHP 8. Now I am at a point where visiting server IP address loads the index.php file but as a plain text instead od executing the script.

As I read, to overcome this, I need to load php module in httpd.conf file. I found the follwoing command

`LoadModule php_module "/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp8.0.so"`

I cannot find libphp8.0.so on my server as I think above command is not for centOS 7. If so then **which php module file I should load and what will be the location of the module on my server?**

Following another blog, I run the below command to install additional php modules

`yum search php-`

But this didn't help.

**UPDATE**

List of installed php packages

```
php80.x86_64                       1.0-3.el7.remi                    @remi-safe 
php80-php-bcmath.x86_64            8.0.15-1.el7.remi                 @remi-safe 
php80-php-cli.x86_64               8.0.15-1.el7.remi                 @remi-safe 
php80-php-common.x86_64            8.0.15-1.el7.remi                 @remi-safe 
php80-php-devel.x86_64             8.0.15-1.el7.remi                 @remi-safe 
php80-php-fpm.x86_64               8.0.15-1.el7.remi                 @remi-safe 
php80-php-gd.x86_64                8.0.15-1.el7.remi                 @remi-safe 
php80-php-mbstring.x86_64          8.0.15-1.el7.remi                 @remi-safe 
php80-php-mysqlnd.x86_64           8.0.15-1.el7.remi                 @remi-safe 
php80-php-pdo.x86_64               8.0.15-1.el7.remi                 @remi-safe 
php80-php-pear.noarch              1:1.10.13-1.el7.remi              @remi-safe 
php80-php-pecl-zip.x86_64          1.20.0-1.el7.remi                 @remi-safe 
php80-php-process.x86_64           8.0.15-1.el7.remi                 @remi-safe 
php80-php-xml.x86_64               8.0.15-1.el7.remi                 @remi-safe 
php80-runtime.x86_64               1.0-3.el7.remi                    @remi-safe
```

Comment: `yum search` does not install anything, it only shows you available packages. CentOS 7 does ship php8, you will need to add a third party repository to be able to install it. If you did that, please show the installed php8 packages.

Comment: Updated the question with installed php packages

Answer (score 1):

Using remi repository, proper configuration and installation explained by the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

You need mod_php, so (as for all extension / sapi)

```
yum install php80-mod_php
```

This module is provided by the php80-php package.

Notice: a better configuration is to use FPM, this is now the default configuration in CentOS 8 and 9.

You can read [PHP Configuration Tips](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips) (for official SCL, up to 7.3, but also work with SCL from remirepo).

Notice: if you need a single version better to use php-* packages as php80-php-* package are designed for parallel installation of multiple versions, as explained by the Wizard.